# Image is missing on site homepage

Tags: images, frontpage

I opened a new site. But my site's home page picture is not seen? It is said that the picture can be seen in the opening of the post. Why do not I install the theme. Which one does not come to the rote page.

My site- https://fileour.com

Please anyone can help me.What is the problem?
Thank you

[image: Image is missing on site homepage]

[image]

Comment: You will need to ask the theme author. Only they can tell you how they built it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you transferred this site from another domain.

For instance, the image on `https://www.fileour.com/test-post-2/` is being pulled from

```
http://www.livetvshow24.ga/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/RX-Entertainment-youtube-cover-photo-300x169.jpg
```

did you work on this site on another domain and then migrate it?  You need to change the db references so the site knows where to pull them from.

Comment: Hey @JacobPeattie, the link in the question says "mysite" so that's what i'm going off for the answer.  If that's wrong we need OP to let us know the real site.